# Cambiar palabra cuando hago Click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

como puedo ocultar la palabra `volver` y que se muestre cuando se abre el `div` que tiene la clase `collapse` y que se oculte la palabra busqueda, es decir que cuando el `div` haga `collapse`, "este `open`" muestre la palabra volver si no esta `open` que muestre la palabra búsqueda, tengo el siguiente código

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html ng-app="myApp"> 
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 
<body>   
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-pills tab-menu tabs nav-search">
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rent-tab">Busqueda avanzada</a>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rent-tab">Volver</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="rent-tab" class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <span>Esto es una prueba</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app="myApp"> 
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 
<body>   
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <ul ng-cloak id="tab-list" class="nav nav-pills tab-menu tabs nav-search">
           <li>
               <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rent-tab" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-hide="toggle">Busqueda</a>
               <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rent-tab" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-show="toggle">Volver</a>
           </li>
       </ul>

       <div id="rent-tab" class="collapse" ng-show="toggle">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-12">
               <span>Esto es una prueba</span>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <script>
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EXPLICACIÓN NG-CLOAK**

`ng-cloak` es una directiva de angular que evita que los elementos tengan un "parpadeo" al cargar la página, cuando se carga el ejemplo se alcanza a apreciar por unos segundos el botón volver y luego se esconde cuando todo termina de cargar correctamente, el ng-cloak se usa para evitar que eso pase.

Comment: Que bien, justamente lo que necesitaba gracias, un aporte: para que no se vea la palabra volver cuando ejecutas el codigo es bueno ponerle ng-cloak a la etiqueta ul, pero ya lo hice gracias.

Comment: Genial, respuesta editada con tu sugerencia ! :D